# Bittorrent and sockets: how to handle multiple messages?

Tags: python, sockets, bittorrent

I'm writing a bittorrent client in python, and have been using a loop to continually read messages from the peer sockets using recv().

When I run my program I look in wireshark to see what bittorrent messages I'm getting. It's pretty easy to tell what kind of message you got from the first 5 bytes of the message, since the length and message ID are specified there.

I'm running into some problems when dealing with receiving data containing multiple messages.

I've tried tackling it by writing a method like this:

```
    def handleMultiple(self, message, peer):
        total_length = len(message)
        parsed = 0
        while parsed < total_length:
            m_len, m_id = struct.unpack(">IB", message[parsed:parsed + 5])
            m_total = m_len + 4
            print(m_len, total_length, parsed, m_id, peer.made_handshake, peer.ip)

            self.handleMessage(message[parsed:m_total + parsed], peer)
            parsed += m_total
```

The function just breaks down the received bytes into its constituent messages and hands it off to the message handler that knows how to deal with individual messages.

The problem is that when I printed out the length prefix and message ID from a message I received using recv(), sometimes it looks like just garbage numbers.

This is really my first time experimenting with sockets, so I lack the intuition to know what I'm really getting when calling recv(). Should I just call receive on the first 5 bytes of data I get, then do some checking to make sure that the length and ID are valid, then call recv() on the rest of the message?

How should I go about handling multiple messages incoming at a time?

Edit:
I wanted to provide some images of the results I'm seeing to see if anyone can help identify the issue I'm having. 
Here's a picture of the bittorrent messages I'm receiving:
[image: Wireshark Capture]

Here's a corresponding logging output:
The columns are supposed to be message length + 4, total message length, message id, and the IP from the sender:

[image]

As I can see, the length prefix for the first messages, (the ones that are multiple messages sent to me at a time) are completely too large. The fifth message I got from 95.211.212.26 is a well formed bitfield message.

Another thing I noticed is that the supposed message ID from each of the multi-message messages is 255. Also given that the total length of a bitfield message for this given torrent is 126, the total lengths (303, 328, 325) are not inconceivable for messages of a bitfield followed by several have messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I've managed to figure out where I was going wrong. I was reading from the socket assuming that my message would be there in full. In reality, I was reading the initial snippet of the message, and at a later time I was reading the middle of the message. The 255 values I was seeing weren't message IDs but actually the middle of the peer's bitfield (0xff).

I changed my approach to store the read in bytes from the socket to the peer's message buffer. Once the message buffer was at least as long as the expected payload, I read the message and trimmed the buffer to exclude what I just read. Now all of my messages' IDs are looking as I expect.